# ¿Cómo hacer un switch con diversas opciones en java y que permita interactuar a la vez con el contenido del array?

Tags: java

Estoy realizando unos ejercicios para clase de programación, y me han pedido realizar un array bidimensional que albergue 3 películas con un total de 12 puntuaciones:

```
String[][]pelis = new String [5][3];

pelis[0][0]= "Batman";
pelis[0][1]="El señor de los anillos";
pelis [0][2]="Avatar";
pelis [1][0]="8";
pelis [1][1]="9";
pelis [1][2]="8";
pelis[2][0]="7";
pelis[2][1]="8";
pelis[2][2]="10";
pelis[3][0]="9";
pelis[3][1]="10";
pelis[3][2]="9";
pelis[4][0]="6";
pelis[4][1]="7";
pelis[4][2]="8";

 for (int i = 0; i <5; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j <3; j++) {
         System.out.println(pelis[i][j]);
         
     }
```

Hasta ahí todo correcto, sin fallo alguno, me pide luego que realice 4 opciones por consola, y cada opción tiene una función determinada en el array, como pedir que muestra el nombre de las películas y puntuaciones, modificar los valores..

¿Para poder realizar esto, como debo proceder?

Entiendo que habría que realizar un switch, pero no se me ocurre como hacer un switch que modifique a su vez el contenido de los array. No quiero una solución ni mucho menos que quiero aprender, solo algunos tips para ver si salgo de este bucle que tengo en la cabeza..

Muchas gracias!

---

Por ahora llevo esto, ahora el problema lo tengo cuando quiero modificar en el comando 2, las películas almacenadas en el array, y las puntuaciones que es el comando 3, que imagino que es el mismo razonamiento que para el 2º caso, he probado con nextLine pero no me funciona y me da error al modificarlo.

```
String[][]pelis = new String [5][3];
    
    pelis[0][0]="Batman";
    pelis[0][1]="El señor de los anillos";
    pelis[0][2]="Avatar";
    pelis[1][0]="8";
    pelis[1][1]="9";
    pelis[1][2]="8";
    pelis[2][0]="7";
    pelis[2][1]="8";
    pelis[2][2]="10";
    pelis[3][0]="9";
    pelis[3][1]="10";
    pelis[3][2]="9";
    pelis[4][0]="6";
    pelis[4][1]="7";
    pelis[4][2]="8";
     
    for (int x = 0; x < pelis.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < pelis[x].length; y++) {
            System.out.println(pelis[x][y]);
            
        }
    }
    
    
    
    Scanner sn = new Scanner (System.in);
    
    boolean salir = false;
    
    int opcion;
    
    
    while (!salir){
         System.out.println("1.Mostrar el nombre y puntuaciones de todas las películas");
         System.out.println("2.Modificar el nombre de una película según su posición en el array");
         System.out.println("3.Modificar una puntuación de una película según su posición en el array");
         System.out.println("4.Mostrar las puntuaciones de una película en concreto seleccionada según su posición en el array");
         System.out.println("Para salir teclee salir");
         System.out.println("Ingrese una opción: ");
    opcion = sn.nextInt();
    
    switch (opcion){
        case 1 -> {
            System.out.println("Ha seleccionado la opcion 1, se le muestran los nombres de las películas y sus puntuaciones");
            
            for (int x = 0; x < pelis.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < pelis[x].length; y++) {
            System.out.println("[" + x + " , " + y + " ] = " + pelis[x][y]);
            
        }
    }
            
            }
        
        case 2 -> System.out.println("Ha seleccionado la opcion 2, modifique el nombre de la película que quiera en el array");
        
                    
                    for (int y = 0; y < 3 ; y++){
                pelis[0][in.nextLine];
            }
        
        
        
        
        
        case 3 -> System.out.println("Ha seleccionado la opcion 3, modifique la puntuación de la película en el array");
        case 4 -> System.out.println("Ha seleccionado la opción 4, se mostrára las puntuaciones de una pélicula en concreto");
    }    
     
    
    
}
}
}
```

Comment: Tendrás que mostrar un menu con las opciones, esperar que pulse una y entonces crear un switch case que contemple todas las opciones del menú, y dentro de cada una, haces lo que sea que haya que hacer. El array será visible si lo defines fuera del switch y todos los case podrán hacer uso de él. Todo ello lo metes en un bucle para que al terminar una opción vuelva a mostrar el menú hasta que pulses la opción de salir y terminar. Tienes mil ejemplos en internet: menu de opciones en consola java.

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a buscar y probar otra vez!

Comment: Hola Israel, por lo que veo en tu código hasta ahora solo tienes la información y ahora quieres ofrecer al usuario poder interactuar con esa información que tienes. 1.- Tienes que realizar el método main donde pidas al usuario que opción requiere, mostrar nombre, mostrar calificaciones o modificar los valores, dependiendo de lo que el usuario escoja (aquí es donde va el switch) es que debes de llamar a otro método el cual haga lo que se te pida, ahora te sugiero hagas un método en donde tengas lo que ahora ya se tiene y solo tener un parámetro.. sigue en el sig comentario.

Comment: En este último método tener el o los parámetros necesarios (corrigiendo el anterior comentario) y he aquí donde debes de tener las 3 funcionalidades y dependiendo de lo que el usuario quiera hacer (que muestre nombres, calificaciones o hacer algún update).Debes de pedir la información (parámetros.).. Si te confunde puedes compartir lo que haz hecho hasta el momento y te ayudo a solucionar el problema, saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias Omar,  por ahora he realizado lo siguiente: